# How can I make the header in React Native Navigation stay in a fixed position when navigating to another screen?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Currently, I have a header for my screens in my React Native app where I have applied the "slide_from_right" animation to each screen. I am using react native navigation built in header props for my screens. Whenever I navigate to another screen, the header moves along with the screen. I would like to have my header stay in a fixed position and whenever I navigate to another screen, the values in the header should change without moving the animation itself.

As you can see in the code below I have tried to add a header in a stack group, but I can't seem to find any way that allows me to set the header behavior for the screens?

```
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#222222'},
        header: ({navigation, route, options, back}) => {
          const title = getHeaderTitle(options, route.name);
          return (
            <Header
              title={title}
              leftButton={
                back ? (
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons
                    name="arrow-left"
                    size={32}
                    onPress={navigation.goBack}
                    color={'white'}
                  />
                ) : undefined
              }
              style={options.headerStyle}
            />
          );
        },
      }}>
      <Stack.Group
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#222222'},
          header: ({navigation, route, options, back}) => {
            const title = getHeaderTitle(options, route.name);
            return (
              <Header
                title={title}
                leftButton={
                  back ? (
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons
                      name="arrow-left"
                      size={32}
                      onPress={navigation.goBack}
                      color={'white'}
                    />
                  ) : undefined
                }
                style={options.headerStyle}
                bottomNavigatorHeaderButton={[
                  {
                    title: 'Expenses',
                    onClick: () =>
                      navigation.navigate('RegistrationBankTransactionScreen'),
                    active:
                      route.name == 'RegistrationBankTransactionScreen'
                        ? true
                        : false,
                  },

                  {
                    title: 'Income',
                    onClick: () =>
                      navigation.navigate('RegistrationIncomeSetupScreen'),
                    active:
                      route.name == 'RegistrationIncomeSetupScreen'
                        ? true
                        : false,
                  },
                ]}
              />
            );
          },
        }}>
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

How can I achieve this?